# Importing python packages within python packages (relative imports, __init__.py)

Tags: python-import, python-packaging

Let's say I have a directory like [this](https://github.com/ekim322/package_import_example)

In `main.py` I have the code `from main_package import func` but I get an error saying

```
test/main_package/func.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sub_package.aa import aaf1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sub_package'
```

The line `from sub_pacakage.aa import aaf1` in `main_package/func.py` is causing the error. I can switch that line to an asbolute path (`from main_package.sub_pacakage.aa import aaf1`) and it works fine.

However, I want to not change the relative path to an absolute path.

I am assuming I have to modify `main_package/__init__.py` to achieve this but I am not sure how. How do I go about this?
I've tried adding `from . import sub_package` to `main_package/__init__.py` but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: I know that is not what you want to hear but my advice is to always use absolute imports. In my opinion relative imports offer little to no advantage and quite a lot of disadvantages. -- Anyway, for relative imports, I guess that in `main_package/func.py` you want to have `from .sub_package.aa import aaf1` (note the leading dot `.`).

Comment: Relative imports are superior to absolute imports because they allow you to move around (reorganize) code without being forced to change it (given the relations are intact). Thus a clear recommendation is to use always relative imports for your own code and only 3rd party external libs should be imported with absolute imports.